# How can I gain access to the Windows 10 BitLocker encrypted drive on Mac OSX?

Tags: macbook-pro

My friends send me a USB drive which has been encrypted with a password in Windows 10 before. There are many important photos for our travel. But when I inserted it on my MacBook. It gave me the windows that the disk was not readable by this computer. I have the password and can not access the drive to get what I want!! Bad mood.

Can anyone give me suggestions? I search online and found there is a tool called iSunshare BitLocker Genius. Did anyone use it before? I know nothing about computer, just want the simplest way to get the photos and share the happy times with my family. Help!

Answer (score 2):

By default, we couldn't open, read and write a BitLocker drive on Mac. But take it easy, the [BitLocker Genius](https://www.isunshare.com/bitlocker-genius/user-guide.html) tool is a really simple and user-friendly tool that can help you get access to the BitLocker drive without any data loss.

When you meet "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer" error, you can click on Ignore button. I'm also a user that know little about computer. But I insert the drive to Mac and type my password then that drive is able to work normally.

Besides, you can unlock the BitLocker encrypted drive on Mac using a recovery key as well.

Comment: Will it make any changes to my photos? The photos are important to me!

Comment: Don't worry, it won't take any damage to your files including photos on this drive.

Comment: Thanks. I tried iSunshare BitLocker Genius and got all the photos to transfer on my Mac.  As you said, It is simple and with no data loss. I guess what if the software can help me turn off BitLocker encryption on Mac, it would be better. Now I only have to format it.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge neither Apple nor Microsoft offer a way to read a Bitlocker encrypted drive on macOS.

A little searching turned up a utility called "M3" from a company called [M3 Data Recovery](https://www.m3datarecovery.com/mac-bitlocker/open-bitlocker-encrypted-usb-drive-mac-osx.html) that purports to enable Macs to read Bitlocker encrypted drives.

Note that I have **ZERO** experience or knowledge of this utility, how good it is, how well it works, or anything else. So use it at your own risk.

Personally I'd just ask whoever sent you the encrypted drive to just put the files on an unencrypted drive. Or give them an ExFAT formatted USB key of sufficient size and ask them to put the files there.

Comment: Thanks, My friend and I are in different cities. So considering the safety of the data, he protected it with BitLocker password. I think it is right, after all, no one knows what will happen during the express delivery. I checked M3 data recovery, the price is higher than what I mentioned tool. I need to think twice and compared more.

Comment: You could have him put the files in an encrypted zip file. There are utilities on the mac that will open those...

Comment: You are brilliant! It is a pity that he did not do that before. I think he did not think more and just keep doing the encryption as he did always.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the password, and you know that the drive works in Windows, then I think the simplest way would be to borrow a computer with Windows and copy the files off the drive to another drive that you can use with your Mac. Alternatively, get a copy of Windows and run on your Mac with VirtualBox, VMWare, etc.., should be able to copy the files to your host Mac system with shared directory or something. It looks like you can download a Windows ISO [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), which you would use to create the virtual machine on your Mac, not sure if you need a registration key just to install and load the OS, in my past experiences you've been able to get to the desktop without registering.

Comment: I asked my colleagues and they did not use Windows laptop. I don't know why. I get used to Mac. But what you said seems to be complex. Could you tell me what is VirtualBox?

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ Virtual Box is a virtual machine client, frequently used to run another operating system inside your current system. So you can use it to run Windows inside your Mac. Its not a perfect solution for all things, and it takes some configuration, but it can likely accomplish this. You will need to install VirtualBox, and you will need a copy of a Windows ISO like the one in the other link I posted, for it to work.

Comment: Ok. Learned more. Got it even it seems complex to me.

Answer (score 1):

Apple still does not provide an official tool to access BitLocker encrypted driver on Mac. Mostly because BitLocker is a patent protected technology. You have to use third-party apps to complete the job up to now.

On My MacBook Pro with Catalina, I am able to unlock a BitLocker HDD with [UUByte BitLocker Geeker](https://www.uubyte.com/bitlocker-reader-for-mac.html). After that, I can easily read files from or write files to that drive.

Answer (score -2):

macOS only can read an NTFS volume but can't Write and Copy files from an NTFS formatted drive. Only FAT32 or exFAT. And Bitlocker is a Windows encryption program which is not supported on macOS,so,you may need a professional utility to unlock bitlocker-encrypted drive on your macOS, or you can open BitLocker USB drive on Mac using Virtualbox.
See more: https://www.sysgeeker.com/how-to-open-bitLocker-encrypted-drive-on-mac.html

Answer (score -3):

Have you resolved your question? Normally, you cannot access a drive encrypted with Windows BitLocker on Mac OS X because Mac OS X doesn’t support BitLocker. To access a BitLocker drive on Mac OS X, you have to firstly connect the drive to a Windows computer and then simply go to **Control Panel > System and Security > BitLocker Drive Encryption** to turn off BitLocker encryption on this drive. If you cannot find any Windows machine, you have to use a third-party utility to access the BitLocker drive on Mac OS X. I found this utility called [BitLocker Reader for Mac](https://www.isumsoft.com/bitlocker-reader-for-mac/) at Google. You can give it a try. Good luck.